# How to fix InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306:3306' (11001 getaddrinfo failed)

Tags: python, mysql

my MySQL connection is successful but ran into this interface errror

```py
import mysql.connector

db=mysql.connector.connect(
    host="127.0.0.1:3306",
    user="root",
    passwd="teja",
    database="test"
)
```

```
InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306:3306' (11001 getaddrinfo failed)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the ":3306" out of the "host" line - mysql connector is adding the port in itself leading to an invalid address.

For future reference if you *do* need to specify a port then you can just specify a separate parameter like so:

```py
import mysql.connector

db=mysql.connector.connect(
   host="127.0.0.1",
   port="3306",
   user="root",
   passwd="teja",
   database="test"
)
```

You don't need to though - 3306 is the default MySQL port and it would appear that's what you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
import mysql.connector

# establishing the connection
conn = mysql.connector.connect(
    user='root', host='localhost', port=3306, database='test')

cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you edit your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?