# Create engine Python MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to connect to an AWS database. 
Connection string is as below.

```
connection_string = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://[username]:[password]@[rds_host]:[3306]/[database1]', echo = False)
```

Username, password, rds_host, etc are defined elsewhere.

Error is as below:

> pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'rds_host]:[3306' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)")

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Removing tag `pandas` as it has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: Apologies - yes I have just deleted.

Comment: Have you checked `ping rds_host` and `telnet rds_host 3306`. It seems that you cannout access your server.

Comment: Is `rds_host` the name of a variable? What's the actual hostname?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306:3306' (11001 getaddrinfo failed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57222529/how-to-fix-interfaceerror-2003-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-127-0-0-1330)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine    
connection_string = "mysql+pymysql://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s" % (USER, PASSWORD, HOST, PORT, DATABASE)
engine = create_engine(connection_string)
```

Marked as answer (thanks!). 
For redshift: 
    connection_string = create_engine("postgresql://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s" % (username, password, HOST, PORT, DATABASE))

Comment: connection_string = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s" % (username, password, rds_host, 3306, db_name)) for MySQL